# BarcodeScanner on PhoneGap 1.5 for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use the BarcodeScanner PhoneGap plugin on the new PhoneGap 1.5 but can't compile it.
I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner
But it seems to be for the previous releases.

I'm using the Xcode 4.2, PhoneGap 1.5 and building for iOS 4.0+

Has anyone got this plugin working in PhoneGap 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

Hi new updation available  that supports upto 2.0 https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap 1.5 has come up with a major change which broke many things. I see it's backward compatible but not completely sure.

I just wrote a YouTubeUploader plugin with Phonegap 1.5 and realized instead of Phonegap it's Cordova stuff there. So if the plugin doesn't work, try modifying source code to use Cordova naming instad of Phonegap.

I will write about my plugin soon.